# What do the following symbols mean in this paper?

Tags: notation, mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations, quantum-information

Due to my limited knowledge, when I read the [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6636034&tag=1) by Mattia Zorzi. I am confused about its notation. Hope you can help me explain.

See *Zorzi, Mattia; Ticozzi, Francesco; Ferrante, Augusto*, [**Minimum relative entropy for quantum estimation: feasibility and general solution**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TIT.2013.2286087), IEEE Trans. Inf. Theory 60, No. 1, 357-367 (2014). [ZBL1364.81074](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1364.81074).,

1. In equation 29, the authors wrote $\delta \mathcal{L}(\rho, \lambda; \delta \rho)$, I don’t know the meaning of the semicolon in brackets, i.e, $; \delta \rho$.
2. In Equation 36, the authors wrote $\left\langle\lambda^{\perp}, \bar{f}\right\rangle$, where $\lambda=\left[\begin{array}{lll}\lambda_{1} & \ldots & \lambda_{m}\end{array}\right]^{T} \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $\bar{f}=\left[\begin{array}{lll}\bar{f}_{1} & \ldots & \bar{f}_{m}\end{array}\right]^{T}$. I don’t know what the $\lambda^{\perp}$ means.
3. In mathematics, what do $\operatorname{Range}$ and $\operatorname{range}$ stand for respectively. For example, the authors wrote  "note that $\left\langle\lambda^{\perp}, \bar{f}\right\rangle=0$ for each $\lambda^{\perp} \in[\text { Range } L]^{\perp}$" and "Notice that in order to have bounded values of the entropy it is only necessary that range $(\rho) \subseteq \operatorname{range}(\tau)$".

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to say, your question is slightly not about calculus of variations, because authors deal with finite-dimensional optimizations (minimizing functions with finite-dimensional argument), whereas calculus of variations is about infinite-dimensional arguments (for example, functions).

1. As it said below that equation, $\delta \rho$ means “direction” in $\mathcal{H}_n$, which is the space of all Hermitian matrices of dimension $n$. When you think about derivative in ordinary multidimensional calculus (with vectors as function arguments) you consider the change of some function $f(\vec{x})$ in some direction $\vec{h}$, that is $f(\vec{x}+\vec{h})$, and in given problem you minimize $\mathcal{L}(\rho, \lambda)$ over matrices, so direction also has to be a matrix.
2. I think that $\lambda^\perp$ is just an authors’ way to note that $\lambda$ comes from the set $[\mathrm{Range} \;L]^\perp$, which is an “orthogonal complement” of $\mathrm{Range} \; L$ – in general, set of all vectors orthogonal to each vector of set $\mathrm{Range} \; L$, and $L$ is defined as linear operator from $\mathcal{H}_n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.
3. For any function, range is the set of all values it can take, and linear operator (matrix) $A$ is a special case of function: $\mathbb{R}^n \ni x \mapsto Ax \in \mathbb{R}^m$. For Hermitian matrix $\mathcal{H}: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, eigenvectors form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, so each $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is uniquely represented as $v = v_1 + v_2$, where $v_1 \in \mathrm{Range} \; \mathcal{H}$ and $v_2 \in \mathrm{Ker} \; \mathcal{H} = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \mathcal{H}x = 0 \right\}$. Let $u$ be a vector such that $\mathcal{H} u=0$, and $v$ be any vector. Thus,
   $\langle u, \mathcal{H} v\rangle=\left\langle \mathcal{H}^{*} u, v\right\rangle=\langle \mathcal{H} u, v\rangle=\langle 0, v\rangle=0$. As eigenvectors of Hermitian matrix corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthogonal, it follows that
   $\mathrm{Range} \; \mathcal{H}$ is spanned by eigenvectors with non-zero eigenvalues and $\mathrm{Ker} \; \mathcal{H}$ - with zero eigenvalues.

EDIT: added some detailed information to 3.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I have some further questions. 1. Does " $\delta$ " in  $\delta \mathcal{L}(\rho, \lambda ; \delta \rho)$ represent a small change like derivative "d"? 2.As it said that  $L$ is defined as linear operator from $\mathcal{H}_{n}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, What does Range $L$ mean? Maybe you already answered in the third question. I am not sure that you said "range" in answer of third question inclouds "Range".

Comment: 3. The third question comes from "Notice that in order to have bounded values of the entropy it is only necessary that range $(\rho) \subseteq \operatorname{range}(\tau)$.,", where I think the authors said "entropy" means quantum relative entropy, i.e., $\mathbb{S}(\rho||\tau)= tr(\rho \log \rho - \rho \log \tau)$. I know it have unbounded values if the kernel of σ (the vector space spanned by the eigenvectors of σ with eigenvalue 0) has non-trivial intersection with the support of ρ (the vector space spanned by the eigenvectors of ρ with non-zero eigenvalue), and is finite otherwise.

Comment: but I can not connect this statement with  $\operatorname{range}(\rho) \subseteq \operatorname{range}(\tau)$ by referring to your explanation about $\operatorname{range}(\rho)$.  Looking forward to your further help, thank you!

Comment: 1. If you mean $\delta$ in $\delta \mathcal{L}$ – yes, “first variation” is the generalization of first derivative in the sense that it’s linear (in $\vec{h}$) part of $f(\vec{x} + \vec{h}) - f(\vec{x})$ for some direction $\vec{h}$. 2. Yes, “range” and “Range” should mean the same. However, I haven’t found $\mathrm{range}(\rho) \subset \mathrm{range}(\tau)$ in the given paper. I could answer with certain provided the reference to this notation.

Comment: $\operatorname{range}(\rho) \subseteq \operatorname{range}(\tau)$ appears in the upper paragraph of formula 24, i.e., Problem 5.

Comment: I prefer to "Range" represents you said "the set of all values it can take". But I am still not sure about the meaning of "range". Thank you for your help again.

Comment: I have no possibility to read the paper on IEEE website, so I’ve been looking thought arXiv version at https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.6658 and there is no such statement.

Comment: Yeah, the arxiv version indeed does not have such statements. The published version adds some statements after equation 23 in the arxiv version. "Notice that in order to have bounded values of the entropy it is only necessary that  $\operatorname{range}(\rho) \subseteq \operatorname{range}(\tau)$. However, whether a certain $\tau$ is acceptable can be determined only after having analyzed the data and found the minimal kernel $\mathcal{K}$. In order to avoid this complication, it is convenient to choose a $\tau \in \operatorname{int}\left(\mathcal{D}_{n}\right)$ from the beginning. "

Comment: " Full rank $\tau$ can be chosen arbitrarily close to any prior state with nontrivial kernel." 
The following sentence is followed by " In the effort of keeping..." in the arxiv version. Thank you for your help again.  If you need the published version, I can send you by email.

Comment: I’ve thought about your comment about nontrivial intersection. It’s a fact from linear algebra that for Hermitian operator $H$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathrm{Range}(H) = [\mathrm{Ker}(H)]^\perp$, their intersection is $\{0\}$ and their union is $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $\mathrm{Range}(\rho) \subseteq \mathrm{Range}(\tau)$, then it follows that $\mathrm{Range}(\rho) \cap \mathrm{Ker}(\tau) \subseteq \mathrm{Range}(\tau) \cap \mathrm{Ker}(\tau) = \{0\}$, so $\mathrm{Range}(\rho) \cap \mathrm{Ker}(\tau)$ is itself trivial, which is needed.

Comment: By definition, $\operatorname{supp}(\rho) = \operatorname{ker}(\rho)^{\perp}$, where $\operatorname{supp}(\rho) $ is the support of ρ (the vector space spanned by the eigenvectors of ρ with non-zero eigenvalue). In fact, the authors of this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.03521.pdf wrote this nontrivial intersection as  $\operatorname{supp}(\rho) = \operatorname{supp}(\tau)$. From your comment, it seems that you mean $\operatorname{Range}(\rho) = \operatorname{supp}(\rho)$. Are they equivalent?

Comment: Yes, you are right, in this case they mean the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128881/discussion-between-curry-and-yalikesifulei).